# Error while converting docx to pdf Cannot read the array length because "this.NewSubrsIndexNonCID" is null

Tags: java, xdocreport

I use xdocreport with the follow dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>xdocreport</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.docx.xwpf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
   ITemplateEngine templateEngine = VelocityTemplateEngine.getDefault();
InputStream in= new FileInputStream(new File("ODTHelloWordWithVelocity.odt"));
IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in,templateEngine);

// 2) Create Java model context 
IContext context = report.createContext();
context.put("name", "world");

// 3) Set PDF as format converter
Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF);

// 3) Generate report by merging Java model with the ODT and convert it to PDF
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("ODTHelloWordWithVelocity_Out.odt"));
report.convert(context, options, out);
```

and, as result:

com.lowagie.text.ExceptionConverter: Cannot read the array length because "this.NewSubrsIndexNonCID" is null

How to fix it, What NewSubrsIndexNonCID is ?
I expect to get pdf document. If I use Doc4j, it works as expected. But DOC4J is very slowly. To convert 4 pages to pdf it takes about 5 seconds and above.

UPD. Stack trace:
2023-08-29T18:11:38.381+03:00 ERROR 13480 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] f.o.x.c.d.p.i.XWPF2PDFViaITextConverter  : java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "this.NewSubrsIndexNonCID" is null
2023-08-29T18:11:38.385+03:00 ERROR 13480 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.XDocConverterException: fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.core.XWPFConverterException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "this.NewSubrsIndexNonCID" is null] with root cause

com.lowagie.text.ExceptionConverter: Cannot read the array length because "this.NewSubrsIndexNonCID" is null

looks like problem with fonts. If I use Calibri, it works fine.

Ok, I try add new fonts:

```
    @PostConstruct
public void init() {
    var fonts = resourceLoader.getResources("classpath:fonts/*");
    for (var font : fonts) {
        FontFactory.register(font.getURL().toString());
    }
}
```

But result the same....

Comment: `ODTHelloWordWithVelocity.odt` is in docx format ? you should post the stack trace ?

Comment: A also tried .docx , the same result

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly the same code running with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.odt</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.velocity</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport.converter.odt.odfdom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


    try {
        ITemplateEngine templateEngine = new VelocityTemplateEngine(new Properties());
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(templatePath));
        IXDocReport report = XDocReportRegistry.getRegistry().loadReport(in, templateEngine);

        IContext context = report.createContext();
        context.putMap(map);
        Options options = Options.getTo(ConverterTypeTo.PDF);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2048);
        report.convert(context, options, out);
        out.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (XDocReportException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
```